# Hide a view when the soft keyboard is showing

Tags: android, android-view, android-softkeyboard

Below pics will better tell you then words that what i exactly wants()..

Before showing softKeyBoard screen is..

[image]

and

After Showing softKeyboard it should look like this..

[image]

My Problem is that when softkeyboard is showing it hide my bottom view which i dont want
to hide but should showing like in above image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify windowSoftInputMode as "adjustResize" in your manifest for the corresponding activity
Example:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".LoginActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: thanks for supporting..will back soon to accept answer if it works..:)

Comment: ok..got it..Actually i have used Linear Layout for that but now its worked fine with Relative layout..And Yes android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" is the perfect answer for the same..:):) Thanks Again